# Microsoft Web Deploy 3.0 - A certificate chain could not be built to a trusted root authority?

Tags: webdeploy

I installed Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate to test the product. At the end of installation, following message was displayed.

"Microsoft Web Deploy 3.0 - A certificate chain could not be built to a trusted root authority."

I need to ask, if I do not fix this issue then what shall happen? Shall I be able to provide deployment package ? Or Is not it effect the coding / project phases?

I am looking forward.

Comment: Was "Microsoft web deploy v3" successfully installed? You can check in <SystemDrive>\program files\iis\microsoft web deploy v3 and see if you msdeploy.exe and Microsoft.Web.Deployment.dll there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download the root certificate updates and then 'repair' your Visual Studio installation.

"This problem occurs because some components in Visual Studio 2012 are signed by a Certificate Authority that is not installed on Windows 7 or Windows Server 2008 R2. Computers that are not connected to the Internet cannot automatically download these certificates." - http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2746268

Comment: Where do I download the root certificate? There is no download link in the KB article

Comment: The resolution section on the link above contains a link to another KB ([KB931125](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/dn265983.aspx)). In there, on the "Important" section is a link to a couple of KBs ([KB2677070](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2677070) and [KB2813430](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2813430)) where you can download the files relevant to your OS.